How do I tell Mr. Scarletella my name?
Near the end of Chapter 2 of Homicipher, there is a section where Mr. Scarletella asks you for your name. A field appears where you can enter text. When you first play this section, your character cannot remember their name. However, in a later chapter you learn the character's name is:

 Adami Adashino

I tried going back to enter the name, but Mr. Scarletella told me the name was incorrect.
How do I tell Mr. Scarletella my name?


If you're doing this for the special ending, assuming it doesn't matter if it's here or Chapter 5...
Especially since reddit says:

on my first playthrough when I got too excited figuring out he was asking for “Name” and rushed to give him the answer… Oops. Guess even Mr. Crawling can’t save me from my stupidity hahaha

So it seems possible...
Maybe it's Developer's Foresight and you have to give your chosen name as TVTropes implies?

The first real thing that you learn about Mr. Scarletella is that he can steal your soul if you tell him your name. You can still input [...] whichever name you gave [...] when he asks. It at least nets you a unique game over.

